# Writing unit testings for hive on local machine

Tags: java, spring, testing, hadoop, hive

I am trying to write unit testings using Java/JS for our Hive sql's.

So when we modify our queries we want to test it on **sample** small amount of data on local machine for testing purposes.

How would you do that using Java? Which framework? Spring or??Which env to configure? any suggestaions?

thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used HiveRunner library. You can simulate Hive tables and sql statements using unit testings